# Selenium: selecting element based on sibling element text

Tags: jquery, css, selenium, testing, xpath

I have been working on a selenium script for:
http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html?dir=asc&order=position

and want to select the element `"Add to Compare"` for `"Sony Xperia"` but its not locating.
I have tried with `cssSelector` and `xpath` both but not able to figure out what i am doing wrong.

CSS Selector:

`div.category-products > ul > li:nth-child(n):contains('Sony Xperia') > div > div.actions > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a`

XPath:

`//h2/a[@title='Sony Xperia']/ul/li/a[text()='Add to Compare']`

NOTE: The `cssSelector` is locating in Chrome but not giving any result in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second row the part you lost

```
//h2[a[@title='Sony Xperia']]
 /following-sibling::div[@class='actions']
 /ul/li/a[text()='Add to Compare']
```

Comment: In your answer: //h2[a[@title='Sony Xperia']] 
you used square brackets before 'a' so why it should not be '/'
as 'a' is not attribute of h2.
Correct me as my understanding is that [] is used for attribute for an element.

Comment: with square brackets it finds h2 which has tag `a` with condition. With clash it finds tag `a` and then finds from it

Comment: Thanks it worked. But can correct it on cssSelector also as its working in chrome but in firefox its not locating

Comment: i have no browsers, except Chrome, so i can't test it

Answer (score 0):

This will be the xpath which shall work everywhere.

xpath: `//h2/a[@title='Sony Xperia']/../following-sibling::div[3]/ul/li[2]/a`

See the steps below to understand it in detail.

Step 1: Navigate to a fix node of the element: `//h2/a[@title='Sony Xperia']` (you have already done this)

Step 2: Navigate to it's parent by adding `/..`

Step 3: Navigate to it's sibling 'Actions' `/following-sibling::div[3]` as the 'Action' class is on 3rd position from current location

Step 4: Go inside the actions node and reach at 'ul' `/ul`

Step 5: Now 'Add to compare' exists inside the second 'li' so add `/li[2]`

Step 6: As 'Add to compare' is a link, it will be inside an 'a' so add `/a`